# Algebraic planar curve with precisely $n$ closed components?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, plane-geometry

For each integer $n$ I am looking for a real-valued polynomial in two variables, $A_n(x,y)$, such that $A_n(x,y) = 0$ defines a curve with precisely $n$ closed components in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Could someone point me in the direction of a theorem or result that might partially/fully solve this problem?

I should point out that the curves must not be concentric, i.e. one should not contain another in its interior.

Comment: The zero scheme of $\prod_{i=1}^n ( (x-3i)^2+y^2-1)$ is such a plane curve.  There are many others.

Comment: How does one prove this?

Comment: How does one prove what?  How does one prove that a product of real numbers equals zero if and only if one of the factors equals zero?  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, sorry, I rushed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Take any polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ with $n$ distinct roots. The curve
$|P(z)|^2=\epsilon$, where $z=x+iy$, is algebraic and has $n$ components when $\epsilon$ is small
enough. This curve is called a lemniscate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is @JasonStarr's polynomial for $n=5$:
$$
 \left((x-3)^2+y^2-1\right)
 \left((x-6)^2+y^2-1\right)
 \left((x-9)^2+y^2-1\right)
 \left((x-12)^2+y^2-1\right)
\left((x-15)^2+y^2-1\right)
$$
And here is a plot of its zeros:

---

[image: JasonStarr]

---

Comment: What is this plot good for? Visualizing a *complicated* example ...?